# show the visualization of the dataset before and after classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Kindly, I am trying to create an ML model using SVM using a dataset with 23 features and the output should be (0 or 1) which means two classes. My Target to show the visualization before and after the classification.

```
import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
        
    ds= pd.read_csv("dataset_sdn.csv") 
    ds= ds.fillna(0) 
    X = ds.iloc[: , [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21]]   # Input Features  
    Y = ds.iloc[:, 22]  # OutPut
    
    X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test = train_test_split (X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
    sc_X = StandardScaler()
    X_Train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_Train)
    X_Test = sc_X.transform(X_Test)
```

Then i tried to visualization the X and Y

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

But i got error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [11], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 plt.scatter(X,Y)
      3 plt.show()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2817, in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)    2812 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.scatter)    2813 def scatter(    2814         x, y, s=None, c=None, marker=None, cmap=None, norm=None,  2815         vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, *,    2816         edgecolors=None, plotnonfinite=False, data=None,
**kwargs):
-> 2817     __ret = gca().scatter(    2818         x, y, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,    2819         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,    2820         edgecolors=edgecolors, plotnonfinite=plotnonfinite,    2821        
**({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)    2822     sci(__ret)    2823     return __ret

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1414, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)    1411 @functools.wraps(func)    1412 def inner(ax, *args, data=None,
**kwargs):    1413     if data is None:
-> 1414         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)    1416     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1417     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)    1418        or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:4368, in Axes.scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)    4366 y = np.ma.ravel(y)    4367 if x.size != y.size:
-> 4368     raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")    4370 if s is None:    4371     s = (20 if rcParams['_internal.classic_mode'] else    4372          rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.0)

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Then i start the classification

```
 classifier = SVC (kernel='rbf', C=1, random_state=0,)
    classifier.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)
    Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_Test)
    print (Y_pred)
```

The I tried to use below code but not work

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
plot_decision_regions(X=X_Test, y=Y_Test, clf=classifier, legend=1)
```

I get this error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [10], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
----> 2 plot_decision_regions(X=Y_Test, y=X_Test, clf=classifier,legend=2)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\plotting\decision_regions.py:148, in plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf, feature_index, filler_feature_values, filler_feature_ranges, ax, X_highlight, zoom_factor, legend, hide_spines, markers, colors, scatter_kwargs, contourf_kwargs, contour_kwargs, scatter_highlight_kwargs)
     44 def plot_decision_regions(
     45     X,
     46     y,    (...)
     65     scatter_highlight_kwargs=None,
     66 ):
     67     """Plot decision regions of a classifier.
     68 
     69     Please note that this functions assumes that class labels are    (...)
    145 
    146     """
--> 148     check_Xy(X, y, y_int=True)  # Validate X and y arrays
    149     dim = X.shape[1]
    151     if ax is None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\utils\checking.py:16, in check_Xy(X, y, y_int)
     12 def check_Xy(X, y, y_int=True):
     13 
     14     # check types
     15     if not isinstance(X, np.ndarray):
---> 16         raise ValueError("X must be a NumPy array. Found %s" % type(X))
     17     if not isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
     18         raise ValueError("y must be a NumPy array. Found %s" % type(y))

ValueError: X must be a NumPy array. Found <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So, please your advice to how show the visualization. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See here:

```
X = ds.iloc[: , [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21]]   # Input Features  
Y = ds.iloc[:, 22]  # OutPut
```

and then here

```
plt.scatter(X,Y)
```

Your `X` vector is multi-dimensional vector having a size of `16` and hence the scatterplot is not working. **You can only plot 2 variables in a 2D scatterplot.**

So you have plot for each feature vs Y, *e.g.,*

```
plt.scatter(X.iloc[:,0], Y)
```